# What is the relationship between view key and random r value for pedersen commitment?

Tags: viewkey

Suppose I make a transaction from User1 to User2 with TX amount 2.5 XMR using RingCT. The transaction amount is encrypted using Pedersen commitment with a random value r.

I have a public view key of PubView1 for the transaction.
Can I see the transaction amount if I only have the public view key? I don't have the "r" value.
What is the relationship between view key and the random r value in Pedersen commitment?

Answer (score 1):

> The transaction amount is encrypted using Pedersen commitment with a random value r.

The amount is encrypted using the shared secret `rA` and committed to in a Pederson commitment.

Amount encryption:

```
b = n xor8 Hs(“amount”|Hs(rA|i))
```

Where `n` here denotes the unencrypted amount, `rA` is the shared secret, `i` is the output index, `|` is concatenation, `Hs` is hash to scalar and `b` is the final encrypted amount.

Then the Pedersen commitment `C`:

```
y = Hs(“commitment mask”|Hs(rA|i))
C = yG + bH
```

So one either needs `r` or `a` (private terms of the shared secret) and either `R` or `A` respectively, the public terms. `R` is `rG`, the tx public key and `A` is the receivers public view key. Thus with `a` (the receivers private key) and the tx public key `R`, one can decode the amount. As can the sender as they have `r` and `A`. This is because `rA == aR`.

> Can I see the transaction amount if I only have the public view key?

No. You need some secret information, either `r` or `a`.

> What is the relationship between view key and the random r value in Pedersen commitment?

See above.

Comment: thank you for your answer! it's helped me to understand more